# Developing JMeter test plan with results from multiple REST end points

Tags: jmeter

Is this possible in JMeter to develop a test plan that will have result of first test (an ID) will be input of next test and so on in next test upto 4 tests because each test generates a unique ID and each of these IDs are dependent on each other. Each one is related as follows: submission ID > execution ID > both will generate completion ID with result pass or fail. These are REST API calls. I need to run concurrency users load testing. Finally I need measure latency, throughput from each test.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but your question is too broad to provide any practical example (there are many ways to do it, depending on how your test plan looks like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should  look something like this.

```
Thread group
     Userdefined variables
     Http Sampler
       Regex to get id
     Http Sampler
       Regex to get id
```

If you want to measure the response time of all the sampler have a simple controller as parent of all samplers

Answer (score 2):

Between sampler requests, parse the api response using JSON post processor, assign it to ${variable_name} and use it in other requests.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for quick tip. I was able to get one step working by passing ID into a regular expression, but the same regular expression did not work for 3rd step. Let me give more details here. Basically first post command gives submission ID > I used that ID into regular expression > run a get command in next step with an URL something like '/../2ndStep/submissionId' > this is passed > I'm using the same regular expression in next get command with an URL something like '/../3rdStep/submissionId/executions'> this is supposed to give another executionId and it is failing for me. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: If I pass the variable value in the sampler like this instead of variable name, the test is passed. /../3rdStep/${submissionId}/executions/. I hope this is correct way of passing in next samplers

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for suggesting working solution. But I need to do this different way to achieve the following requirement.

When I run POST command test on my REST API HTTP request using JMeter, it returns an ID in response. This ID will be used by other steps for completing the job. I'm currently passing ID into regular expression and using that in between the samplers of each step as it was suggested above and then measuring latency, but the GET steps which are dependent on that ID could take sometime to complete. So I can not put those GET steps into one thread because two of the steps are failing as they could take some time to complete. Is there a way to separate POST command from the remaining and start polling GET commands on the remaining steps automatically to remedy this. Bottom line is I need to measure latency of each step and throughput too. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this in JMeter? 
Thanks again, 
Santana